# Reason why $x \mapsto x^p$ is a ring morphism in characteristic $p$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, positive-characteristic

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring of characteristic $p$, where $p$ is prime.
The Frobenius map $x \mapsto x^p$ on $R$ is known to be a ring homomorphism (in particular, additive).

The only proof I know of this fact is to use binomial expansion and then $p \mid {p\choose k}$ for every $0<k<p$. But what are some other proofs? Are there "conceptual" reason for such a canonical morphism to exist?

Comment: Can you clarify why you fin the binomial theorem argument non-conceptual? The only possible barrier to homomorphism-hood is additivity, and the additivity requirement is precisely $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$, and it's clear that this would hold *if* all the nontrivial coefficients in the binomial expansion are multiples of $p$. So if you find this latter fact - "all but the first and last terms in the binomial expansion of $(x+y)^p$ have coefficients which are multiples of $p$" - conceptually clear, you should be happy with the existing proof.

Comment: Incidentally, here's my favorite proof of that fact. For $S\subseteq\{0,1,..., p-1\}$ and $a\in \{0,1,...,p-1\}$, let $S+a=\{(s+a)mod p: s\in S\}$. Think of $S+a$ as gotten by "shifting" $S$ over by $a$ *(and then modding out appropriately)*. This defines an equivalence relation on subsets of $\{0,1,..., p-1\}$: namely, $S\sim T$ iff $S$ is a "shift" of $T$. Now for $0<k<p$, the set of $k$-element subsets of $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$ is partitioned into $\sim$-classes, and each $\sim$-class has cardinality $p$ *(here's where $0<k<p$ is used)*, so the number of $k$-element subsets is a multiple of $p$!